# How do I create a ReactJS chrome extension that can open a new tab from a popup?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, react-router

I am creating a chrome extension using ReactJS. I essentially want to have two pages - One for the popup and a second page to be opened in a new tab by clicking a button on the popup.

Comment: See documentation and examples for `chrome.tabs.create`.

Comment: There are several ways you can do this. Start with a [ReactJS and Chrome API sample](https://engineering.musefind.com/how-to-build-a-chrome-extension-with-react-js-e2bae31747fc). Follow the [chrome.tabs.create](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-create) like woxxom said. There's plenty of samples from [chrome-extensions-examples](https://github.com/orbitbot/chrome-extensions-examples)

Comment: I am also stuck on the same problem. I've tried using react router, but on opening in a new page, it tells me that the page has been deleted. the link works fine in the same page tho.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly I suggest following this tutorial for the basics.

https://medium.com/@gilfink/building-a-chrome-extension-using-react-c5bfe45aaf36

This would help a ton with the basics. A general summary is that you want to change the manifest.json in the **public folder** to what a chrome extension manifest.json would look like. Within that manifest.json, you want to add the index.html (also in the public folder) to be called wherever you want it to be called really.

Example here below:

```
{
     "manifest_version": 2,
     "short_name": "XXX",
     "name": "XXX",
     "version": "1.0.2",

     "browser_action": {
         "default_popup": "index.html", //popup page occurs when you click on the favicon
         "default_title": "Open the popup"
     },

     "chrome_url_overrides": {
         "newtab": "index.html" //registers an override page (index.html) to the newtab page.
     }
}
```

Overriding other pages:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/override

**NOTE**: Make sure that after building it with npm run build and when choosing the chrome extension in "Load Unpackaged" that you are picking the build folder and not the public folder.

Comment: Also make sure to approve this answer if it works for you!